# Notification Widget showing download progress

Tags: ios, animation, notifications, widget, today-extension

Is it possible to update a today widget to show download progress of a file?

Here is my code for the Today Extension:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userDefaultsDidChange:) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 50);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateProgress) name:@"UpdateWidget" object:nil];

    [self updateProgress];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)userDefaultsDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self updateProgress];
}

- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResultFailed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResultNoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResultNewData

    [self updateProgress];

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
}

- (void)updateProgress
{
    double progress = 0;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.xxx.xxxx"];
    progress = [defaults doubleForKey:@"Percent"];
    _percentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f%%", progress];

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self updateProgress];
}
```

And then here is where I update the user defaults in the app:

```
double currentProgress = totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.xxx.xxxx"];
[defaults setDouble:(currentProgress*100) forKey:@"Percent"];
[defaults synchronize];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateWidget" object:nil];
```

What do I need to change? Is this even possible what I am trying to do? I also want to show a progress bar updating as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this using:

```
CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateProgress)];
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.